# jQuery UI Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I have the following script with a UI Datepicker, but I need the date as a param in my URL.. I just can't seem to get the date formatted correctly in the URL.. The input box with the date are just fine but the date don't show up in my URL string..

I need the dateText variable to be formatted as "yyyy-mm-dd"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#datepick').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" })({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        window.location.href="reports?date=" + dateText;
    }
    })
});
</script>
```

Thank you..

Comment: What are you currently seeing? The date is not populated or the date is in the wrong format?

Comment: What error are you getting? The JavaScript you provided is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this within your onSelect:

```
window.location.href="reports?date=" + $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
```

Comment: No problem. Please click on the tick icon to mark this as answered if it solved the issue, it makes us stack overflow people happy :)

Comment: What difference does this make, as opposed to the question?

Comment: @WilliamNiu not sure what you mean...?

Comment: I believe `$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker("getDate")) == dateText`.